# How to select Array element with Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to implement a Cypher Query to select an element inside an Array.
This is my csv row:

```
user_id,name,review_count,friends,useful,funny,cool
ntlvfPzc8eglqvk92iDIAw,Rafael,553,"['oeMvJh94PiGQnx_6GlndPQ', 'wm1z1PaJKvHgSDRKfwhfDg', 'IkRib6Xs91PPW7pon7VVig', 'A8Aq8f0-XvLBcyMk2GJdJQ']",628,225,227
```

I want to select, for example, friends[0] and find him proprieties.
Query will be like this:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.name = 'Rafael' RETURN ??u.friends[0], u.friends[1] ..??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, it would be more convenient to change your CSV file's data format for the `friends` column to be a semicolon-delimited list (assuming that no list element will ever contain a semicolon or comma), like this:

```
user_id,name,review_count,friends,useful,funny,cool
ntlvfPzc8eglqvk92iDIAw,Rafael,553,oeMvJh94PiGQnx_6GlndPQ;wm1z1PaJKvHgSDRKfwhfDg;IkRib6Xs91PPW7pon7VVig;A8Aq8f0-XvLBcyMk2GJdJQ,628,225,227
```

Once that is done, you can import the `User` nodes like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' AS row
MERGE (u:User {id: row.user_id})
SET u += row{
  .name, .useful, .funny, .cool,
  review_count: TOINTEGER(row.review_count),
  friends: SPLIT(row.friends, ';')
}
RETURN u
```

And after importing is completed, this query:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.name = 'Rafael'
RETURN u.friends
```

will return:

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"u.friends"                                                                                          │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│["oeMvJh94PiGQnx_6GlndPQ","wm1z1PaJKvHgSDRKfwhfDg","IkRib6Xs91PPW7pon7VVig","A8Aq8f0-XvLBcyMk2GJdJQ"]│
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

[UPDATE]

If you want to create unique `FRIEND` relationships with the friends (instead of creating a `friends` property), this should work:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' AS row
MERGE (u:User {id: row.user_id})
SET u += row{
  .name, .useful, .funny, .cool,
  review_count: TOINTEGER(row.review_count)
}
UNWIND SPLIT(row.friends, ';') AS friendId
MERGE (f:User {id: friendId})
MERGE (u)-[:FRIEND]-(f)
RETURN u
```

`MERGE (u)-[:FRIEND]-(f)` uses an *undirected* relationship, and will only create the relationship if there is not already one (in either direction).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I change my csv like your example, but I can't access to friends.
Premise: I'm using opencypher/morpheus [link](https://github.com/opencypher/morpheus)

I want to use "IN" query, like: `MATCH (u:User)-[:Friend]->(u2:User) WHERE u.user_id IN u2.friends RETURN u2.user_id`  (or something like that)

Comment: My answer creates a `User` node with the `id` property, not `user_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a doubt, how can I create User nodes in Friendship relationship with other User nodes (according to the table shown)?